# Google Cloud Storage - Failed to upload a file using Chrome

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm getting an error message "Failed to upload a file" when uploading from Chrome (same error whether i'm using drag and drop or the file selector). There is no detail in the error message so I have not idea how to fix this.

[image: Please see a screenshot of the error message]

I was able upload the same file from gcloud shell using this command:

```
gsutil cp <file> gs://<bucket>
```

I also checked the followings:

1. Permissions - should not be an issue because I was able to upload from the shell. Also i'm the storage admin
2. Checked the Google Cloud Log Viewer - I don't see any entry for the failed attempts, only the successful one that I initiated from the shell
3. I tried to upload from Chrome on Mac and different one from Linux machine and getting the same error
4. This is an old bucket and I used to upload from the browser many times in the past

Any idea what can be causing this issue?

Comment: Open the Chrome debugger (Press F12). Repeat upload. Do you see any error or warning messages? What is the size of the file?

Comment: Is this issue persistent? If you close the windows and open them again is still happening?
Could you indicate the chrome version?

Comment: The problem has been resolved apparently without me doing anything. It didn't work on Friday and yesterday but today it's fine. I'll check again in few days